# Date and time stored on variables don't refresh while page

Tags: php, date, datetime

Date and time are setted to Madrid's standard UTC, and stored for translation and formatting in this way:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
$dia=""; $mes=""; $dia2=""; $ano=""; $horaActual=""; $minutoActual="";

        $dia=date("l");
        if ($dia=="Monday") {$dia="Lunes";}         if ($dia=="Tuesday") {$dia="Martes";}        if ($dia=="Wednesday") {$dia="Miércoles";}        if ($dia=="Thursday") {$dia="Jueves";}        if ($dia=="Friday") {$dia="Viernes";}        if ($dia=="Saturday") {$dia="Sabado";}        if ($dia=="Sunday") {$dia="Domingo";}

        $mes=date("F");
        if ($mes=="January") {$mes="Enero";}        if ($mes=="February") {$mes="Febrero";}        if ($mes=="March") {$mes="Marzo";}        if ($mes=="April") {$mes="Abril";}        if ($mes=="May") {$mes="Mayo";}        if ($mes=="June") {$mes="Junio";}        if ($mes=="July") {$mes="Julio";}        if ($mes=="August") {$mes="Agosto";}       if ($mes=="September") {$mes="Setiembre";}        if ($mes=="October") {$mes="Octubre";}        if ($mes=="November") {$mes="Noviembre";}        if ($mes=="December") {$mes="Diciembre";}

        $dia2=date("d"); 
        $ano=date("Y");
        $horaActual=date("H");
        $minutoActual=date("m");
```

This gives the same time and date all the time (I created this an hour ago), not refreshing while web browser does. In this right moment, this code:

```
<?php echo  "$dia $dia2 de $mes, $horaActual:$minutoActual"; echo "--" date("F j, Y, g:i a");?>
```

Shows:

**Lunes 26 de Mayo, 16:05 -- May 26, 2014, 5:03 pm**

So `date()` is getting the correct and updated info, but variables are not updating this info, showing stucked data from the first time they stored this values.

every time user gets inside this url, date and time must be updated with actual values

Comment: refresh how? using an ajax call? or you're hitting `ctrl-r`?

Comment: A normal refresh, maybe F5 or just going to other section and coming back to this section, loading again the page

Comment: going/coming back may be cached by your browser. use a forced refresh, e.g. `shift-ctrl-r`, which tells the browser to ignore the cache and hit the server for a fresh copy.

Comment: That will no solve the problem, because every time user gets inside this url, date and time must be updated with actual values

Comment: then you'll either need some JS code to fetch the new data via ajax, or output appropriate http headers to make the page non-cacheable

Comment: JS is OK, is there any way of checking actual date and time with it? Please mention on answer and I'll tick. I did not know I could solve this with JS or jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how your time got stuck, but alternatively you could do this (time updated). Consider this example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
$dia = $mes = $dia2 = $ano = $horaActual = $minutoActual = "";
$days = array('Monday' => 'Lunes', 'Tuesday' => 'Martes', 'Wednesday' => 'Miércoles', 'Thursday' => 'Jueves', 'Friday' => 'Viernes', 'Saturday' => 'Sabado', 'Sunday' => 'Domingo');
$months = array('January' => 'Enero', 'February' => 'Febrero', 'March' => 'Marzo', 'April' => 'Abril', 'May' => 'Mayo', 'June' => 'Junio', 'July' => 'Julio', 'August' => 'Agosto', 'September' => 'Setiembre', 'October' => 'Octube', 'November' => 'Noviembre', 'December' => 'Diciembre');

$dia = date("l");
$mes = date("F");
$dia2 = date("d"); 
$ano = date("Y");
// $horaActual = date("H");
// $minutoActual = date("m");
$time = date('H:i');

echo  "$days[$dia] $dia2 de $months[$mes], $time"; echo "--". date("F j, Y, g:i a");
// outputs: Lunes 26 de Mayo, 17:21--May 26, 2014, 5:21 pm
```

[**Fiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gLPP0d)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the correct way to format it.

Comment: ...and dont know why but this has solved the problem. Now all data is updated. Thank you.